# How to configure an asynchronous web server in the ESP32?

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am trying to do an asynchronous web server using a Sparkfun ESP32 with an ESP32-WROOM-32D and the Arduino IDE for one of my projects. My ultimate goal is to use the WiFi network of the ESP32 as an AP and serve up an asynchronous web page to a connected client, so it can download a text file from the server.

To start my project, I tried to do a simple server just like in this tutorial :[ESP32 Arduino: Asynchronous HTTP web server](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/12/01/esp32-arduino-asynchronous-http-webserver/) , I used the library ESPAsyncWebServer.h :

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "ESP32wifi";
const char* password = "12345679";

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to Wifi..."); 
  }

  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/html", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
    request->send(200, "text/html", "<p>Hello!</p>");
  });

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
}
```

The problem is that everytime I compiled the code there were no errors but when I opened the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE I was stuck in "Connecting to Wifi...", my WiFi.status was never connected.

I then try to solved the problem by reinstalling the libraries the program was using, change the SSID and the password of my network, change the server port to 8080 and use a code with a fixed IP address but my WiFi.status() was still the same.

A couple of days ago I used the same ESP32 as a Soft Access Point for another project with only the WiFi.h library :

```
#include "WiFi.h"

const char* ssid = "ESP32wifi";
const char* password = "12345679";

WiFiServer server(80);
```

I tried my old code again without the asynchronous server code and the SAP worked, so it wasn't a problem with the WiFi antenna. I then decided to try another kind of library that let me configure an asynchronous web server, it was WebServer.h :

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "ESP32wifi";
const char* password = "12345679";

WebServer server(80);
```

But I had the same problem that I had with the AsyncWebServer, my program was stuck in "Connecting to Wifi..." .

So, my question is how can I configure an asynchronous web server in the ESP32 ? 
Could it be a mistake in my code that causes my problem? Is there a way to use the WiFi.h library only for this kind of server?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: how does it matter what server you run, if you can't connect to network? is it a 2.4 GHz WiFi? does the SSID or password use some unusual characters?

Comment: I think the problem commes from the kind of server I am trying to use, because I was able to connect to the network and access a web page with the WiFiServer but not the other two. I am using a 2.4 GHz WiFi. The SSID and password use nombers and letters only.

Comment: as I understand it, SoftAP works and connecting to your WiFi AP doesn't. and that has nothing to do with how do you handle a TCP server

Comment: @Juraj Thank you very much for your advice, I am new in this kind of projects so I don't really know how to approach the problem. I changed the question to better present the problem.

Comment: try the WiFiScan example

Comment: Does the WiFiScan work when the ESP32 is the AP?

Comment: your question is: Why is it stuck in "Connecting to Wifi..." ? That has nothing to do with SoftAP. So why do you ask about Esp32 as AP?

Comment: My previous message was incomplete, sorry. I forgot to mention that I am trying to use the WiFi network of the ESP32 as an AP and serve up an asynchronous web page to a connected client.

Comment: sorry, I forgot for a moment that you work with two esp32. WiFiScan on an esp32 as STA will see the SoftAP of the other esp32. it has still nothing to do with the TCP server

Comment: Thank you very much ! The scan help me found what was wrong with my connection

Comment: So it is possible to have AP mode and AsyncWebServer? why you don't mention what was finally the problem so as to help others too?